# How to use variable inside if from same function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Now I would like to get a variable from if inside same function as if like below.

```
renderItemBox() {
const { store } = this.props;
const currentScreen = this.props.navigation.state.routeName;
AsyncStorage.getItem('openingGenre')
  .then((openingGenreValue) => {
    if (currentScreen === 'EachShopGenreScreen') {
      if (openingGenreValue === 'food') {
        const items = this.store.restourantStore.Items;
      } else {
        Alert.alert('予期せぬ不具合が発生いたしました。再度お試し下さい');
      }
  });
return items.map((value, index) => (


//////
)
```

However, this code is not working, I cannot get "items" from IF on items.map~~~~

Why this is happening?

Could someone help me.

Comment: your code is not clear... please provide full method or class for better understanding...

Comment: I know...But my code is too long...

Comment: based on your code you want to access your items from return right?

Comment: Exactly. I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare items using let as an empty array in the function scope then do your if statement.
Or at least that's one way of doing it.
Btw this is more of a JavaScript question.